# Field Calculator If/Then in ArcGis 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I've been looking through these threads, i found something similar and thought it could be the answer, but it doen't seem to work for me...

I could do this the slow way with Select By Attributes, but It's time consuming and I will have to repeat it several times for other works.

I have a field called "Kultur" (String) with different codes (DG, A, FF, ...). I want to change this information into a numeric information, so i added a new field called "Kultur_Cl" (Short Integer).

In my case if "Kultur" is DG, "Kultur_Cl" should be 1. If "Kultur" is A, "Kultur_Cl" should be 2, ...

Here is what i tried :

[image]

And here is what it looks like in ArcMap:

[image]

Once it's done i would like to do : If "Kultur_Cl" = 1 then "Kultur_Pkt" = 15, if "Kultur_Cl" = 2 then "Kultur_Pkt" = 18, ... Would this go the same way, or is it different because there would only be numeric data?

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: You don't need to pass the DG over to the function so remove both references...also your return lines are missing indentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you need a double == for your test, simple = is for assignment, not testing

second you forgot the indentation and a semi-colon

```
def MyCalc(Kultur,DG):
    if (Kultur == DG):
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

third, DG must be identified as a string

```
MyCalc(!Kultur!,'DG')
```

it would go the same way with numeric values (you don't need quotes in this case)

Comment: Thank you very much !! I'm not very good with Python, still learning... Thanks again :)