# Field calculator if and elseif statement with <Null> values in ArcGis 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, python-parser

Trying to figure out how to get this "Headwater" column to indicate "Yes" (or 1) if the value of "NextDown_Copy" is "" and "No" (or 0) if it has any other value (eg. 7100381010).

[image]

I attempted to try figuring out the Python code to do this using 1 and 0 coding (although I'd rather use Yes and No) (as illustrated below) but keep getting errors. 
I consulted a few other [posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81817/basic-if-then-in-arcgis-10-2-field-calculator-python-or-vb?newreg=b37c19580e464ca4bb4c9b89dd95ed25) ([another one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111432/field-calculator-if-then-in-arcgis-10-1)), but still wasn't able to find the problem.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are missing the indentation in the Code box.

Comment: Sara Barnes, where should the indentation have been?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple expression with no need to define a function in the codeblock:

Headwater =

```
0 if !NextDown_Copy! else 1
```

This checks if each value of NextDown_Copy is truthy (i.e. not a null, 0, empty string), and returns a `0` if so, otherwise it returns a `1`.

Comment: Thanks!  This pretty much worked, although it returned 1s for Null values and left Null in all the rows for which NextDown_Copy had values.  Any ideas why?

Comment: That's very odd. What if you try `1 if !NextDown_Copy! is None else 0`?

Comment: Hum! Good idea. Unfortunately still didn't work!

Comment: Is `Headwater` a text field? If so, try `"0" if !NextDown_Copy! else "1"`

Comment: I just tested all 3 of these options on my own test feature class (in a file geodatabase, where both fields are text-formatted), and all 3 of them worked as expected. How exactly is your data formatted? You're not trying to run this while you have any features selected, right?

Comment: Aha!  Maybe the fiels class is the problem then.  My fields are 'double'. (And no, nothing is selected!)

Comment: I'm at a complete loss as to why this is failing for you. I tested with double fields, too, and it's working for me in ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Comment: Another expression you can try: `(0,1)[bool(!NextDown_Copy!)]`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.  (Looks like today I was making a big mistake by not selecting Python while running the codes... I just realized this, which is likely what was causing the problem, sorry about this!)

Comment: Yeah, that would do it :) If you could mark the answer as correct, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Python uses None to denote null values. I'd replace your Null with None (no quotes or brackets)and see what you get. Your script is essentially looking for a text string value of null. Furthermore, it's not contained in single quotes, so you're throwing a syntax error twice over.

Comment: Tried this out with no luck.  But thanks, as its great to know that Python denotes nulls as None.  I am totally unfamiliar with Python for the moment and was doing guess work, so indeed, I was trying to get it to search for a string value! Good to know I shouldn't have been doing that.