# Multiple calculations with if then statements and NULL values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, if-statement

I'm trying to calculate a total demand in ArcGIS 10.2.2, stored in fields Demand1, Demand2, ... , Demand20. Some of them contain a numeric value. The others have a `<Null>` value. The sum therefore always returns `<Null>`.

I've tried in Python to define, in the pre-script a function:

```
def D(a):
   0 if a else 1
```

(as recommended in [Field calculator if and elseif statement with <Null> values in ArcGis 10.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179607/field-calculator-if-and-elseif-statement-with-null-values-in-arcgis-10-1?lq=1), with correct indents, etc.)

then in the code

```
 D( !Demand1! ) + D( !Demand2! ) + ... + D( !Demand3! )
```

It cannot compute. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're defining a function, you need to use a `return` statement within it for `D()` to actually return a value. Use `return 0 if a else 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The return saved everything, but was more likely 'return a is a else 0' and that way it works.